# Django - Context Variables

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I've been looking all over stack and I just can't get anything to work.

The simpler for of my doubt is, I have a context variable, which I have to reassign inside a `for` loop, and I can, but when a new iteration begins, the variable is reset to it's original context value. So my question is, how do I keep the assigned value persistent throughout the loop?

I am assigning the value like this:

```
{% with task.new_stage as current %}{% endwith %}
```

The full excerpt of the code follows:

```
{% for task in tasks_list %}
<h3>At Beg {{current}}</h3>
{% if task.project_stage.id != current %}
<div id="tasks-container-{{ task.project_stage.id }}" class="task-container btn-group-vertical col-md-3">
{% endif %}
    <div class="panel my-panel tasks-panel col-md-11 {% if task.project_stage.has_started and not task.project_stage.has_ended %}active{% endif %} ">
        <span class="text-uppercase">{{ task.task_name }}</span>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <img id="task-{{ task.id }}" class="download-pdf" src="{% static 'dpp/images/cloud.png' %}" />
        </div>
    </div>
{% if task.project_stage.id != current %}
</div>{% with task.new_stage as current %}<h3>At End{{current}}</h3>{% endwith %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

View:

```
def get(self, request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, 'dpp/login.html', {'form': form})

    tasks_list = ProjectTask.objects.all()
    context = {
        'tasks_list' : tasks_list,
        'current' : 0,
    }
    return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context of `{% with %}` lasts until `{% endwith %}`. You end the block immediately after starting it, so it literally has no effect.

You shouldn't be trying to reassign variables inside the context. If you just want to check if something has changed since the last iteration, you should use the template tag specifically designed for that: [`ifchanged`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged).

Comment: So, now I now a little bit more about Django and it's withs :P
Thanks a million!! I have now been able to do what I wanted